# How to suppress specific chapter number (while keeping the design) in latex?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, fancyhdr, titlesec

I want to suppress the preface number "0'', contents "0'', and index number "5''. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
     \geometry{a4paper, total={120mm,175mm},
             left=20mm,
             top=20mm,
             }
% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\linespread{1.05}         % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amscd,multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp,tikz}

%%% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./zbibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

% Index
\usepackage{calc,epigraph,floatrow,systeme} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
%\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}


%\usepackage{numcompress}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%%%%%%%%%%%        %%%%%%%%%%%%%    %%%%%%%%%%%%     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine}
\allowdisplaybreaks

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}{../Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{Pictures/}{../Pictures/}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customize lists
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reduce spacing between bullet points and numbered lists

\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for nicer horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{eso-pic} % Required for specifying an image background in the title page




%%%%%%% polynomial factorization style file %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polynom}


%%%%%%%%   Tikz draw matters   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,intersections, patterns,calc,angles,quotes,matrix,backgrounds,fit}% pgfplots.fillbetween}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections,plotmarks}

\makeatletter
\def\markxof#1{
\pgf@process{#1}
\pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgfplotsunitxlength +\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin
% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{15pt}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\normalsize\thecontentslabel]{1.2cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{}
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[2.2cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily\small\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.00cm}} % Section number
{}
{\sffamily\small\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[2.6cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\itshape} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.20cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\sffamily\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% Subsubsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[3.0cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\footnotesize} % Spacing and font options for subsubsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.20cm}} % Subsubsection number
{}
{\sffamily\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN CHAPTER HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indendating
{\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\color{blue}\sffamily\small\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\small\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\color{blue}\sffamily\small\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\newcommand{\intoo}[2]{\mathopen{]}#1\,;#2\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{\mathrm{{}d}}\mathopen{}}
\newcommand{\intff}[2]{\mathopen{[}#1\,;#2\mathclose{]}}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[chapter]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% dedicated to boxed/framed environements %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumbox}% % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square

\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumex}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\color{ocre}\nobreakspace\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace
        \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumbox} % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{2ex \@plus 10ex \@minus -.2ex}
%{-2ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
%{10ex \@plus.2ex }
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\color{ocre}\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{0.3ex \@plus.2ex }
{\color{cyan}\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-1ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.1ex}
{.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\color{red}\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-1ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .1ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
            {\color{cyan}\sc\bfseries\Large}
            {\filleft\sc{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
            {1ex}
            {%\titlerule\titlerule
            \vspace{0ex}%default is 0ex
            \centering }

\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%thm-box%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=myblue,
  colback=myblue!20,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=myblue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{algorithm}[1][]{
  mystyle,
  title=Algorithm~\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1]
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries}                    % format applied to label+text
{}                                                      % label
{1pc}                                                   % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
    % draw a box around the chapter number
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,flushright upper,
            boxrule=1.4pt,
            colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
            drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow,
        width=2cm]
        \resizebox{1cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}\Huge} % before the title body
[]                        % after the title body
\begin{document}


\frontmatter

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{0.75cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
%
{\color{red}  \HRule{1.15pt} }                 % Upper rule
{\color{red}{\bf Title}} \\[1.15cm]
\par\normalfont\fontsize{25}{25}\rmfamily\selectfont
{\Large John Doe%, \\[0.2cm]
}


\endgroup

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2021  Publisher Here % Copyright notice

\newpage

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
Title\par % Book title
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\begin{center}
 {\huge \today}
 \vfill
\end{center}
\endgroup

\newpage

%
\chapter{Preface}
\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself
\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

\linespread{1.13}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}


\mainmatter


\pagenumbering{arabic}
 \setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{chapter1}
\index{test}
\chapter{chapter2}
\chapter{chapter3}
\chapter{chapter4}
\chapter{chapter5}



\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you format you chapter headings with `titlesec`, I'd use `\chapter*{Preface}`  and add in the preamble the formatting of such chapters with `\titleformat[numberless]{\chapter}{…}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces the output that meets your three requirements.

Main changes:

(1) Uses `imakeidx` which allows easy redefinition of the index environment and, best of all, only requires one compilation.

(2) Eliminate the boxes of the chapters numbered with zero, including the index, while keeping the layout of the chapter heading.

[image: A]

[image: bx]

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{rgb}{0.69, 0.25, 0.21}% <<< added

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
     \geometry{a4paper, total={120mm,175mm},
             left=20mm,
             top=20mm,
             }
% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\linespread{1.05}         % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amscd,multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp,tikz}

%%% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./zbibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

% Index
\usepackage{calc,epigraph,floatrow,systeme} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
%\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}


%%  %\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
%%  %\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}

%\usepackage{numcompress}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%%%%%%%%%%%        %%%%%%%%%%%%%    %%%%%%%%%%%%     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine}
\allowdisplaybreaks

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}{../Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{Pictures/}{../Pictures/}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customize lists
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reduce spacing between bullet points and numbered lists

\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for nicer horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{eso-pic} % Required for specifying an image background in the title page

%%%%%%% polynomial factorization style file %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polynom}

%%%%%%%%   Tikz draw matters   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,intersections, patterns,calc,angles,quotes,matrix,backgrounds,fit}% pgfplots.fillbetween}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections,plotmarks}

\makeatletter
\def\markxof#1{
\pgf@process{#1}
\pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgfplotsunitxlength +\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin
% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{15pt}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\normalsize\thecontentslabel]{1.2cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{}
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[2.2cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily\small\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.00cm}} % Section number
{}
{\sffamily\small\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[2.6cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\itshape} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.20cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\sffamily\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]
% Subsubsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[3.0cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\footnotesize} % Spacing and font options for subsubsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.20cm}} % Subsubsection number
{}
{\sffamily\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN CHAPTER HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indendating
{\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\color{blue}\sffamily\small\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\small\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\color{blue}\sffamily\small\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\newcommand{\intoo}[2]{\mathopen{]}#1\,;#2\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{\mathrm{{}d}}\mathopen{}}
\newcommand{\intff}[2]{\mathopen{[}#1\,;#2\mathclose{]}}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[chapter]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% dedicated to boxed/framed environements %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumbox}% % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square

\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumex}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\color{ocre}\nobreakspace\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace
        \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumbox} % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace
    
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter   
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
{2ex \@plus 10ex \@minus -.2ex}
%{-2ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
%{10ex \@plus.2ex }
{1ex \@plus.2ex }
{\color{ocre}\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
{-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
{0.3ex \@plus.2ex }
{\color{cyan}\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
{-1ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.1ex}
{.2ex \@plus.2ex }
{\color{ocre}\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
{-1ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .1ex}
{.1ex}
{\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}
\makeatother
    


%   \titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
%               {\color{cyan}\sc\bfseries\Large}
%               {\filleft\sc{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
%               {1ex}
%               {%\titlerule\titlerule
%               \vspace{0ex}%default is 0ex
%               \centering }


%%%%%%%%%%thm-box%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=myblue,
  colback=myblue!20,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=myblue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{algorithm}[1][]{
  mystyle,
  title=Algorithm~\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1]
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
    
%%%**************************************  changed and added
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries}                    % format applied to label+text
{}                                                      % label
{1pc}                                                   % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
    % draw a box around the chapter number
        \vspace*{3ex}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[bicolor,
        colbacklower=white, boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
        colback=white,
        width=2cm]
        \resizebox{1cm}{!}{\color{white}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}\Huge}
[]                        % after the title body
    
\titleformat{name=\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries}                    % format applied to label+text
{}                                                      % label
{1pc}                                                   % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
    % draw a box around the chapter number
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,flushright upper,
        boxrule=1.4pt,
        colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
        drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow,
        width=2cm]
        \resizebox{1cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}\Huge} % before the title body
[]                        % after the title body
                    
%% Make index   
\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}  % <<<< added   
\makeindex[title=Index]     

%Redefine the index environment
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
    \renewcommand{\leftmark}{Index}             
    \chapter*{\color{ocre} \Huge Index}     
    \setlength{\parskip}{\z@ \@plus .3\p@}%
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ \@plus 1fil}%
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
        \let\item\@idxitem
    }{\end{multicols}\clearpage}   
\makeatother

%%%**************************************  end changed and added
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= red,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}


\linespread{1.13}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{0.75cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
%
{\color{ocre}  \HRule{1.15pt} }                 % Upper rule
{\color{ocre}{\bf Title}} \\[1.15cm]
\par\normalfont\fontsize{25}{25}\rmfamily\selectfont
{\Large John Doe%, \\[0.2cm]
}       
\endgroup

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2021  Publisher Here % Copyright notice

\newpage

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
Title\par % Book title
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\begin{center}
 {\huge \today}
 \vfill
\end{center}
\endgroup

\newpage

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Preface}}
\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself
\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}
 \setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{chapter1}
\index{test}
\chapter{chapter2}
\chapter{chapter3}
\chapter{chapter4}
\chapter{chapter5}  

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

%-------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your preamble is a very big mess: you load packages in the wrong order and lose track of what you have already done, loading many of them more than once.

For instance, you're doing twice `\titleformat{chapter}`.

You should dedicate some time to clean it up.

Anyway, here's how you can do for the unnumbered chapters.

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries} % format applied to label+text
  {}                                   % label
  {1pc}                                % horizontal separation between label and title body
  {%
   % draw a box around the chapter number
   \begin{tcolorbox}[
     enhanced,
     flushright upper,
     boxrule=1.4pt,
     colback=white,
     colframe=black!50!yellow,
     drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow,
     width=2cm,
   ]
   \resizebox{1cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
   \end{tcolorbox}\Huge
  } % before the title body

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries} % format applied to label+text
  {}                                   % label
  {1pc}                                % horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\Huge} % before the title body
```